# Существует ли ключ в многомерном массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Есть многомерный массив:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(11) "Rear Window"
    ["director"]=>
    string(16) "Alfred Hitchcock"
    ["year"]=>
    int(1954)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(17) "Full Metal Jacket"
    ["director"]=>
    string(15) "Stanley Kubrick"
    ["year"]=>
    int(1987)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(12) "Mean Streets"
    ["director"]=>
    string(15) "Martin Scorsese"
    ["year"]=>
    int(1973)
  }
}
```

Задача:

Как проверить существует ли в массиве ключ например `year` и не пустой ли он?

Comment: А задача кому?))

Comment: можно array_column использовать, можно цикл обычный и isset, array_key_exists  да мало ещё чего